# Trying to install nodejs 12 on CentOS giving error

Tags: node.js, npm, centos, yum

I am trying to install nodejs on my centos 6 machine version : centos-release-6-10.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64

I am running the following command : -

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum install nodejs
```

I am getting following error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Determining fastest mirrors
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

How to resolve it.

Comment: Try yum clean all and then try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Centos 6 is not supported by NodeJS 12.
Centos 6 uses versions of glibc and libstdc++ that are too low for NodeJS.

You are stuck with version 10 on centos 6.

If you still want to cram NodeJS 12 into Centos 6, then you can do the below, but it may brick other things, do at your own risk.

```
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-common-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-devel-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-headers-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-utils-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-static-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh --nodeps --force \
glibc-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm \
glibc-common-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm \
glibc-devel-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm \
glibc-headers-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm \
glibc-static-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm \
glibc-utils-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm \
libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

And you cannot use the auto installer you have to download NodeJS 12 separately, as the auto installer will not accept Centos 6.